# OpenAM for Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8, openam

I am trying to connect OpenAM with drupal 8 for user's  authentication .
Can we integrate OpenAM with Drupal 8 ? Is there any module available for drupal 8 of OpenAM . Please share .

Answer (score 1):

If you can do OIDC in OpenAM, you just have to install and configure https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect

It redirects you to the authentication provider if you're not connected, then it creates you an account on your drupal if you don't already have one.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 is still recent, and many modules did not migrate to Drupal 8 yet, it's the case with OpenAM, you eaither follow the steps to upgrade this module to the 8 version, or you should Create your own module.

Here's the link to the Drupal 7 module : https://www.drupal.org/project/openam

And here's how you can go about converting a module from 7 to 8 :

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/converting-drupal-7-modules-to-drupal-8

and here's a command line tool that can make upgrading the module to 8 easier for you :

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalmoduleupgrader